# How do I change the default schema in sql developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I don't see any tables in the tables section of a database that I've linked to w/ SQL developer. The DB admin says I need to change the default schema in SQL developer. How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: I requested this feature many years ago: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=43135:7:0::NO:RP,7:P7_ID:2202.  I've long since realized that sometimes you need to pay for good software: http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldevordering.html

Answer (score 106):

```
alter session set current_schema = otheruser;
```

should do the trick.

Comment: This is what everyone will be doing,

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  I'm using version 4.0.2.15

Comment: This may change the current schema in your workbook, but it doesn't affect the object explorer - so I still can't browse the database properly.

Comment: This just gives SQLCODE=-104

Answer (score 25):

Just right clic on the created connection and select "Schema browser", then use the filter to display the desired one.

Cheers.

Comment: this schema browser is not available in 3.2.version . how can i enable in the old version

Answer (score 15):

I don't know of any way doing this in SQL Developer. You can see all the other schemas and their objects (if you have the correct privileges) when looking in "Other Users" -> "< Schemaname >".

In your case, either use the method described above or create a new connection for the schema in which you want to work or create synonyms for all the tables you wish to access.

If you would work in SQL*Plus, issuing `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=MY_NAME` would set your current schema (This is probably what your DBA means).

Comment: The "Other Users" access works, though not very comfortable.

Answer (score 12):

This will not change the default schema in Oracle Sql Developer but I wanted to point out that it is easy to quickly view another user schema, right click the Database Connection:

[image]

Select the user to see the schema for that user

[image]

Comment: Which version of SQL Developer is this?

Comment: ah, the old AAAAAA_ sort method

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively, just select 'Other Users' one of the element shows on the left hand side bottom of the current schema.

Select what ever the schema you want from the available list.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old but...

I found this:

http://javaforge.com/project/schemasel

From the description, after you install the plugin it appears that if you follow the logical connection name with a schema in square brackets, it should connect to the schema by default.

It does but the object browser does not.

Oh well.

Comment: The Schemasel extension is no longer available as Javaforge has changed to (bought by?) Code Beamer, and I can't find any other location for it. Even if it was available, it was built for SQL Developer 3 and is not compatible with SQL Developer 4. Unfortunately, even though SQL Developer 4 supposedly supports extensions, the Oracle extensions page ( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/extensions-083825.html ) doesn't list any extensions for SQL Developer 4. Apparently there is not much interest in that product. I can suggest moving to SQuirreL SQL...

Answer (score 4):

When a new user is created in ORACLE, an empty work area for tables and views is also automatically created.  That work area is called a 'Schema'.  Because of the tightly coupled relationship between users and schemas, the terms are often used synonymously.  SQL Developer will, by default, show the empty schema that belongs to the user you connected with if it is indeed empty.

However, if you click to expand the part of the tree titled 'Other Users', you'll see other users/schemas that your user has access to.  In there, you may find the tables and views you are seeking if you select the correct user/schema.  An object only lives in the schema that owns it.

Still, it would be nice if the application allowed us to pick our desired schema closer to the root of the tree instead of forcing us to go searching for it. Other answers have offered workarounds such as:

1. Logging in as the desired user/schema to begin with.
2. Using a different Tool.
3. Ignoring the tree and just executing: alter session set current_schema = otheruser;
4. Creating a startup script to set the schema every time the application loads.

In the end, I searched and found another free tool that seems to solve this particular usability issue called [DBeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/).

It's all a bit confusing because the word schema is overloaded. Schema could also be used to describe the database of your application. To get more clarity, read more about the term schema as it is used in the ORACLE context.

Answer (score 2):

If you log in as scott, but wish to see the tables for the HR schema, then you need to alter your session "alter session set current_schema=HR;"

If you do this all time, then you can create a startup script called login.sql with the above command in it, then tell SQL Developer to run this at startup via Tool/Preferences/Database

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new connection (hit the green plus sign) and enter the schema name and password of the new default schema your DBA suggested. You can switch between your old schema and the new schema with the pull down menu at the top right end of your window.

Comment: That assumes that you have the password for the user whose schema you want to access. This is not the case for me - I have a some read/write access to the other schema, but not the password for the user of the other schema.

Answer (score 0):

After you granted the permissions to the specified user you have to do this at filtering:

First step:

[image: First Step to change default Tables]

Second step:

[image: Second Step to change default Tables]

Now you will be able to display the tables after you changed the default load Alter session to the desire schema (using a Trigger after LOG ON).

Comment: not working for me 
i can access the tables per query-worksheet, but under the tree they're not visible

Comment: instead <> you can try NOT LIKE option