# Can I set a default schema for a connection in Oracle sql developer 4?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there a way to set the default schema for a Database connection in Oracle SQL Developer version 4+?  I see this link for previous versions:
http://www.javaforge.com/project/schemasel

...but I can't figure it out for Oracle SQL Developer version 4.

Comment: Why not just log in as that schema? Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Sure, that sounds great - how do I do that? :)

Comment: This other post leads me to believe that this is not possible or is at least not straightforward: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407950/how-do-i-change-the-default-schema-in-sql-developer

Comment: [This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-may/o38sql-102034.html) is the basic tutorial on how to add a DB connection in SQL Dev. You can add many connections to a single database and then if you want to connect to say the `HR` schema you can only connect that one while not connecting to `SCOTT`.

Comment: Sure, but my question remains. I still need to know if/how I can set a default schema.

Comment: Your default schema would be whatever one you open the connection with.

Answer (score 7):

The way to do this at the tool level would be to run a session startup script.

1. Create a text file 'logon.sql' with the script "alter session set current_schema = yourschema;"
2. Save it anywhere - I recommend saving it somewhere in your database install location.
3. In SQL Developer go to Tools -> Preferences -> Database
   Check the box for "Run connection startup script on each new database connection"
4. Browse and select the above file.

That should make you default to that schema every time you login.

Comment: This seems to be a global setting.  It would be nice if you could do this with a particular connection.