# Change to other database in sql developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to change the database connection of a SQL worksheet in Sql Developer. For example I'm now working in database connection !OMY_OWNER_C_1 and want to change the database connection to !OMY_OWNER_C_2.

The way I do that now is by clicking on the 'Choose DB connection' button on the top right, and select !OMY_OWNER_C_2, but I want to achieve the same by running some sql.

Can anyone tell me how to that that? (or whether it is possible?)

I already tried some with 'ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = !OMY_OWNER_C_2;', but that does not do the trick.

In other stack overflow threads a simular question is there, and the use of 'ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = !OMY_OWNER_C_2' is suggested, but for me that does not do the trick. I do something wrong or it just can't, or there is something else why it does not work.

In Sql Server I just use 'USE database !OMY_OWNER_C_2', but Oracle/Sql developer works different.

I made two printscreens which makes some above used names more clear hopefully: http://prntscr.com/9mo3us and http://prntscr.com/9mo7hh.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I change the default schema in sql developer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407950/how-do-i-change-the-default-schema-in-sql-developer)

Comment: possibly, I'm not sure

Comment: I needed a similar solution as well and after figuring out a decent way of accomplishing it I came back to this question to give an answer but it was deleted by a moderator (thanks stackoverflow). You can see the answer on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75504182/9666170).

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = SchemaNameTwo` should do the job.
But don't rely on SQL Developers GUI. The field showing the  current schema name doesn't display *SchemaNameTwo* when you fire the alter session command.
Instead: To validate that the schema has changed: use this select:

```
SELECT sys_context( 'userenv', 'current_schema' ) FROM dual;
```

My example:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = minimaks;
SELECT sys_context( 'userenv', 'current_schema' ) FROM dual;
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = minimakskontrol;
SELECT sys_context( 'userenv', 'current_schema' ) FROM dual;
```

Gives this result:

```
Session altered.
SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_SCHEMA')                                        
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
MINIMAKS                                                                        

Session altered.
SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_SCHEMA')                                        
\--------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
MINIMAKSKONTROL
```